# How can the REPLACE command block all other js libraries?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the code I use:

```
 document.addEventListener
(
'DOMContentLoaded', function () 
  {
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/verbe/i, 'VERB');
return;
  }
);
```

It works fine (the string is replaced) but all the javascript libraries (that otherwise work when thoses line are not run) are not run anymore. There is no error on the console, they are simply disregarded by the browser.

Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: So don't do it that way, your replacing the whole HTML's body, I'm supprised the browsers don't crash..  Find another way..

Comment: What do you propose?

Comment: You're pointing to entire body html, try pointing a specific node

Comment: @Needzhelp  You need to explain what your trying to do in more detail, to propose anything specific.

Comment: The reason I'm using this method is that the documetn has to be edited at run time (some strings must be tagged so they appear with a different css. so for example the word "verb" would be transformes into <span id="newformat"> verb </span>. And the string can be anywhere in a complex page...

Comment: I would suggest traversing the DOM, the reason some scripts might stop working, is because they might be attaching event listeners to the DOM, that you have totally destroyed.  If you can also be more specific, eg.  It's all `<span>` tags this would be better too, otherwise your even going to be replacing text inside `<script>` tags etc,  inline styles etc etc..

Comment: I think I understand..
How is it possible to target only strings of text (that is to be read by user) and to insert html elements around them (a, p, span) so I can point to them with css? 
Can you explain "traversing" DOM? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely must go through every text node in the document you can create a [NodeIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator) which has a function letting you loop over every text node of the body:

```js
const patternToReplace = /foo/ig;
const replacement = 'FOO';

const iterator = document.createNodeIterator(
  document.body,
  NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
  (node) => {
    if (patternToReplace.test(node.nodeValue)) {
      return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    }

    return NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
  });

let node;

while ((node = iterator.nextNode()) != null) {
  node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(patternToReplace, replacement);
}
```

`document.createNodeIterator` takes the element whose descendants to iterate over as its first parameter, then the type of nodes as the second (we're only interested in text nodes), and lastly an optional "filter" which you can use to skip all text nodes not matching the pattern.

Then calling `nextNode()` on the returned iterator object lets you walk through all matching text nodes and replace occurrences of the pattern (note I'm using the `g` flag for the regular expression to make sure to match multiple occurrences of the pattern in the same text node).

*update*:

I got a bit off topic, regarding why your libraries stop working I'm not entirely sure. I rarely use `innerHTML`, but my best guess would be that changing the entire `innerHTML` of the body would unregister all events previously set up by the libraries to function. That would not be the case by using a `NodeIterator` though.

Comment: Wow, that look awesome!
I'm checking it out right away (I was just reading about "traversing" the DOM here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-traverse-the-dom, but my pages are too complex and diverse for such cherrypicked targetting. Your solution seems excellent!
I'll be right back!

Comment: I tried it and it totally respects all the other libraries!
Excellent job! You're a DOM saver :-)
However if the const replacement contains html tags I find two cases:

1/if typed like so:

'<span id="mystyle-ing">-ING</span>'

with single quotes, they are parsed as "all text", and the tags are not parsed as html, so everything appears on screen.

2/if they are typed like so:

"<span id="mystyle-ing">-ING</span>"

i.e double quotes, then Nothing happens, the replacement is not effective.

Can you see a workaround?
Many thanks for your great help!

Comment: @Needzhelp If I understand correctly you want to search for a plan string and do some manipulation, but also wrap in new elements?
It seems like [using innerHTML will always unset event listeners](https://friendlybit.com/js/manipulating-innerhtml-removes-events/), so even with NodeIterator that will be a problem.
My best guess would be to use the RegExp match to find the indexes of the matched string, then manually "cut" the Text node into the text before and after the match, and create a new element node for the matched text. Then you have to replace the Text node in the parent.

Comment: So when you say "manually", do you mean using a search and replace tool such as Notepad++ and do it offline?

Comment: @Needzhelp oh, sorry, bad word choice. I meant taking the nodeValue of the Text element, slicing it with the `slice` String function, then creating new text nodes with the sliced string using `document.createTextNode`.
You'll have to use the [match result](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) from the regular expression to find out the indexes to cut at, for instance `match.lastIndex` gives you the end of the matched string. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Emmie for your ongoing help :-) If the searched string is entirely replaced is there a need to slice it?  Would the document.createTextNode be parsed by the browser? If so would it be possible to have a 2-step replace: first a node (with an id) and second its content (the new string of text)?

Comment: @Needzhelp I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at, but the string would be the `nodeValue` of the Text node, which might include a lot more than just the string your were searching for. I assume you want to replace only that part (if not you can use `replaceChild` on the parent node). You can't simply insert an element in the middle of a Text node, so you have to replace it with several nodes (text before + new element + text after).
This can be a bit tricky if you haven't done it before, so I suggest making a new stackoverflow question if you get stuck.

Comment: Thanks Emmie. Indeed, I did not grasp that your proposal would fetch the entire content of the node (usually a whole paragraph within a div). I thought it would be possible to just replace the "patternToReplace" as mentionned in your script wiht both a node (opening and closing html tags as I understand) and the content of that node. Your answer was only partial regarding my needs but I'll accept it as it does prevent destroying the DOM, and I had not mentionned the HTML tag in the initial question :-) Have a nice day.